# Collision of an electron with an atom

Tags: electrons, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, hydrogen

What exactly happens when we say an electron collides with an atom? When we say atom, does the incoming electron collide with the **nucleus** of the atom (electromagnetic repulsion from the nucleus ,relating to Rutherford's scattering formula and the distance of closest approach) or the **valence electrons**/all electrons of the atom? Referring to the Frank-Hertz experiment, how does the incoming electron behave after transferring it's kinetic energy to the atom upon collision??

Comment: Note that the Rutherford formula applies whether the potential is attractive or repulsive. You can use it for nuclear-nuclear scattering, or electron-nuclear scattering, or even comet-sun scattering.

Answer (score 1):

At non-relativistic speeds the interactions are primarily electrostatic. The negatively charged electron is *attracted* to the positively charged nucleus  and *repelled* by the negatively charged electron cloud (aka "valence electrons"). Since the nucleus is much heavier than electrons, it can be considered point-like, but the electron cloud has (in)finite extension.

The difference between Ratherford scattering and Frank-Herz experiment is that in the former the scattering is elastic, whereas in the letter part of the electron energy is transferred to the excitation of the atom (which is usually discussed as an excitation of eletcrons in atom, due to the big mass of the nucleus, already mentioned above). Whether the scattering is elastic or not depends, first of all, on whether electron has sufficient energy to excite the atom to a higher state (typically around the optical range) , but also on the details of the scattering setup.

Comment: Well written Roger! Another thing that intrigues me is the successive current drops at certain voltages in the Frank-Hertz experiment. Does the drops state the quantized energy levels of an electron in the atom? And what happens to the incoming electron after it passes some/all of it's kinetic energy to the gas vapour atom with inelastic collision as you mentioned? Does it contribute to the current plotted in the graph too?

Comment: @PranjalSharma only electrons contribute to the current, since the atoms are neutral. Electrons are accelerated by the voltage towards the anode, and if they gain sufficiently high energy, the lose it in collisions with atoms. Then they are accelerated as again. Because of this inelastic collisions, average electrin velocity drops, and so drops the current. Hence the sawtooth pattern - depending on how many times electron gains enough energy to excite an atom.